# Merge sort implementation using iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, sorting, c++14

Here is my first try to implement merge sort using iterators -

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

namespace base {
namespace merge {

    template <typename Iterator, typename Compare>
    void mergeBack(Iterator begin, Iterator mid, Iterator end, Compare comp)
    {
        typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type ElemType;
        std::vector<ElemType> left, right;

        left.reserve(mid - begin);
        right.reserve(end - mid);

        std::copy(begin, mid, std::back_inserter(left));
        std::copy(mid, end, std::back_inserter(right));

        size_t j = 0, k = 0;
        auto i = begin;
        for (; i != end && j < left.size() && k < right.size(); ++i) {
            *i = comp(left[j], right[k]) ? left[j++] : right[k++];
        }

        while (j < left.size()) {
            *(i++) = left[j++];
        }

        while (k < right.size()) {
            *(i++) = right[k++];
        }
    }


    template <typename Iterator, typename Compare = std::less<>>
    void sort(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Compare comp = Compare())
    {
        if (end - begin > 1) {
            const auto middle = (end - begin) / 2;
            merge::sort(begin, begin + middle, comp);
            merge::sort(begin + middle, end, comp);
            mergeBack(begin, begin + middle, end, comp);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm open to advice/suggestions about the implementation and would love to hear how I could make it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prefer to move values whenever possible.

```
std::move(begin, mid, std::back_inserter(left));
std::move(mid, end, std::back_inserter(right));

size_t j = 0, k = 0;
auto i = begin;

for (; i != end && j < left.size() && k < right.size(); ++i) {
    *i = std::move(comp(left[j], right[k]) ? left[j++] : right[k++]);
}

while (j < left.size()) {
    *(i++) = std::move(left[j++]);
}

while (k < right.size()) {
    *(i++) = std::move(right[k++]);
}
```

Every call of mergeBack will end up allocating 2 new buffers. You can avoid that by preallocating the secondary buffer and flip flopping between them but that is tricky to do in the recursive version. Which is why I prefer the iterative version that goes bottom up.

Comment: if move isn't possible, will that operation fail to compile or switch to copy operation?

Comment: Point of OP is correct, there should be some fallback mechanism. Solution can be [std::move_if_noexcept()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept)

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal, I think that if move isn't possible it will still compile. But if move can throw, the story changes a lot.

Comment: The bottom-up mergesort suffers from the following: suppose the length of the input range is \$2^k + 1\$, where \$k\$ is a positive integer. Now the very last merge will merge a run of length \$2^k\$ with a run of length of one element. (One single element will introduce an entire pass over the range.)

Comment: @coderodde you can adjust for that by letting the last range be larger by doing a extra merge if the last block size < 0.5*the current block size

Comment: Never done that before. Yet I have to disagree with *that is tricky to do in the recursive version*. After all, in your top recursive call there is only two cases to try what comes to the initial source/target array arrangement.

Comment: @coderodde the tricky part is at the recursion stop to decide whether to swap in place on length == 2 or do a merge to the other buffer. Which requires passing down a flag to know where the result should end up (into src or dst).